# Compound noun Vs Adverb of time

Tags: grammar, tense, word-usage

Please let me know, in the following context either "Now-a-days" is Adverb of time or Compound Noun?

> I don’t watch TV very much now-a-days. There’s so much rubbish on. It’s not like it used to be.
>
> Young people now-a-days don’t respect their teachers any more.

Comment: Just a small side note: We don't hyphenate the word *nowadays*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Nowadays* is an adverb of time similar in meaning to *currently* or *presently*. It is written as one word without hyphenation (i.e. nowadays, **not** now-a-days or now a days).

In your last example sentence, the use of *nowadays* with *any more* (or *anymore*, depending on what side of the [debate](http://alt-usage-english.org/anymore.html) you fall on) is rather redundant. You could simply say:

> Young people nowadays don't respect their teachers.

or

> Young people don't respect their teachers anymore.

Both sentences imply that young people respected their teachers in the past, though that implication is stronger/clearer in the second sentence.